# Is this a violation of the Pigeonhole Principle?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

Given a set $S$ of elements [1, to 21] generate a list of permutations fixed to a constant of $3$.

$P(n,r)$=$P(21,3)$

$=21!/(21−3)!$

$= 7980$ **possible permutations of 3-element sets**

Fact: There are $23940$ elements altogether; because $7980*3 = 23940$ and there are 3-elements in each set. Remember this is a list of permutations of $3$ generated from elements from $S$.

Consider that, I have a select few $3$-$element$ sets but with two empty slots in each set. The empty slots can ONLY be filled from elements in $S$. (But can only be an exact cover of $S$)

**Example:**

$(1,~,~)$$(2,~,~)$$(3,~,~)$$(4,~,~)$$(5,~,~)$$(6,~,~)$$(7,~,~)$

Remember that our list $S$ has integers [1, to 21] and $21$/$3$ $=$ $7$.

I can find the set difference to see what elements I need.

**Set difference:**

I crossed out the elements that exist in the sets above to see what
I need.

$S$ = $X,X,X,X,X,X,X,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21$

I need $14$ integers to create an exact cover for $S$.

$Needed~~elements$ = $8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21$

### Violation of the Pigeonhole Principle??

I need $14!$ orderings below to find all possible Exact Covers that have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 starting at the first in each set of $3$

$(1,~,~)$$(2,~,~)$$(3,~,~)$$(4,~,~)$$(5,~,~)$$(6,~,~)$$(7,~,~)$

Well, that's bad news... $14!$ = $87178291200$ and $14!$ > 7980*3 or $23940$ elements.

### Question

How is it even possible to have $14!$ orderings in $23940$ elements of the list we just generated?

Comment: I am having serious thoughts that I encountered some mathematical paradox and I'm an amateur. So please explain this to me. Because this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Your figure of $14!$ is the number of **sequences** of $7$ ordered triples from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,21\}$ such that

- $1$ appears in the first triple, $2$ in the second, and so on through $7$, and
- each integer in the set appears in exactly one of the ordered triples.

It’s perfectly true that there there are only $7980$ different ordered triples from that set and that listing them would entail listing $3\cdot7980=23,940$ individual members of that set, but those figures has only a **very** indirect connection with what your $14!$ is counting.

Comment: What happens if I had only one slot and filled all $i$,$N$ for every triplet, and created a list of all them?? Oppss. Something is not right. Or I am confused.

Comment: @DingleBerry: I don’t understand your question, I’m afraid.

Comment: Give me about 10-15 minutes and I'll be able to tell you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS2fq.png I couldn't fit in here, so I made an image.

Comment: @DingleBerry: You’ve demonstrated that there are $7!=5040$ permutations of the set $\{15,16,17,18,19,20,21\}$ and that each of them can be used to produce a different sequence of $7$ ordered triples satisfying some very restrictive conditions. Bluntly, so what? This really has almost nothing to do with the number of different ordered triples.

Comment: So every permutation of 7 elements (w/o) repeating will always share a set for all sets in the example demonstrated? (eg. given the slots)

Comment: @DingleBerry: No. The sequence $\langle 1,2,3\rangle$, $\langle 4,5,6\rangle$, $\langle 7,8,9\rangle$, $\langle 10,11,12\rangle$, $\langle 13,14,15\rangle$, $\langle 16,17,18\rangle$, $\langle 19,20,21\rangle$ shares **no** ordered triples with your $5040$ sequences.

Comment: But $3,6,9,12$ are not the needed_elements. $15,16,17,18,19,20,21$ are our 7 elements. 3,6,9,12 do not exist in the 7 elements

Comment: @DingleBerry: Then I don’t understand what question you were trying to ask in your previous comment. All that I can tell is that you have some very fundamental confusion(s) that I cannot pin down. Until you figure out how to communicate clearly just what the problem is, I doubt that I can say anything useful.

Comment: I find it paradoxical that all n! orderings for the single slots w/o repeating can share all those sets w/o overlap. There isn't even n! sets in the first place in the restricted case!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you down to the statement that there are $23940$ elements in all the $3$ element permutations from $S$.  The next sentence makes no sense at all.  It appears you are computing the number of ways of filling in your $7$ tuples (not sets because they are ordered) with the other $14$ elements of $S$.  Yes, there are $14!$ ways to do that.  Why should that have any relation to the $23940$ number?  There are $7980$ three tuples.  You are selecting some of them with restrictions.  There are lots of ways to do that.  They have no relation to $3$ times the number of tuples you are selecting from.

Comment: Okay, then what are all possible orderings of the 14 elements without repeating? Must it be < 23940 steps? That ordering has to exist in the list.

Comment: Not at all.  It is $14!$ as you say.

Comment: then 14! must exist in the list if we generate all possible orderings of 3 without repeating.

Comment: @DingleBerry: But the $14!$ isn’t counting individual triplets: it’s counting whole **sequences** of triplets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So what is the correct value of all possible orderings of those 14 elements that would fit in the slots (w/o repeating)?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Shouldn't all sequences of 3 exist in our list of permutations?

Comment: As we both said, it is $14!$, which agrees with you.  The problem is that you think this should have some relation to $23940$ or $7980$.  There is another layer of combinatorics because you are selecting $7$ of the $7980\ 3-$tuples with restrictions.  That explodes the number.

Comment: @RossMillikan But, shouldn't those sequences of 3 exist in the list of permutations if we are generating ALL possible 3 permutations?

Comment: NO.  A list of permutations is like $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  There are $6$ in the list.  Now we are asking how many lists of three of them there are.  These are things like $(1,2,3), (5,2,4)$ and so on.  There are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4=120$ in that list.  You are confusing the two.  A list of permutations is a list of lists.

Comment: @DingleBerry: Of course. But your $14!$ isn’t counting sequences of $3$: it’s counting certain kinds of sequences of $7$ sequences of $3$! It doesn’t count some of sequences of $3$, like $\langle 1,2,8\rangle$, at all, but it counts others, like $\langle 1,8,9\rangle$ many, many times over.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Generating all (and all means all including sequences of 7 of 3!)orderings of 3 should've been trivial. I don't see why there is such a blowup.

Comment: @DingleBerry: Because you’re counting completely different things, and there are far more of one kind of thing than there are of the other!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This was interesting, I just learned how to calculate how many possible solutions could exist. (for a given ordering)